# Change color of a Resource

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have created a resource in my project as follows:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Color x:Key="BgColor">#FFFFFF</Color>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

 <RelativeLayout x:Name="Layout" BackgroundColor="{x:DynamicResource BgColor}">
```

when I try to change the color of the resource, in theory it should change the background color, but it doesn't happen

```
private void SwitchTheme_Toggled(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
{
     App.Current.Resources["BgColor"] = "#282928";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I try to change the color of the resource, in theory it should change the background color, but it doesn't happen.

You can try the following code:

```
  <ContentPage.Resources>
    <Color x:Key="BgColor">red</Color>
</ContentPage.Resources>

  private void btn1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Resources["BgColor"] = Color.FromHex("#F15A29"); or using
        //Resources["BgColor"] = Color.Green; or using
        Resources["BgColor"] = "#282928";         
    }
```

If you create ResourceDictionary in App.xaml, you can use  `Application.Current.Resources["BgColor"]` it works fine.

Comment: Thank you! what changes between creating a ResourceDictionary or as you showed me? what are the differences in practice?

Comment: @signalover From the effect of the code, it has some difference. Application.Current.Resources seems that contains resources in App.xaml, but Resources contains resources in contentpage.resources.